Why compiling occurs when making minor code changes while running npm run serve
Why does it compile when making small changes to the code while running
npm run serve

, and is this behavior normal? I would like to know if the server should recompile for every change, even if it is a small change like deleting an HTML element or modifying CSS.
I tried to temporarily disable HMR in vue.config.js and restart it but it didn't work and HMR is enabled by default.

The server doesn't know now care how big a change is. It sees a file change, it recompiles.

How many lines should, in your opinion, your code have changed, in order to trigge a recompile?

This is a feature called hot reload. Search for hot-reload-uncache-modules in your configuration and make sure it's disabled.
